# How can I follow the next iteration of a loop until a promise is fulfilled?

Tags: javascript

I'm basically using Node.js to write a .json file, for that I want to write a new file `"n"` times according to my `aArray`, but my problem is that it always shows the last position (`third.json`). Is there any way I can continue with the next iteration as long as the file is created?

My output desired is the creation of each .json file with the names of my array

```
first.json
second.json
third.json

aData={ ..... }
var aArray=["first.json","second.json","third.json"];
for(var i in aArray){
    fs.writeFile(aArray[i], JSON.stringify(aData, null, 4), 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
        console.log(err);
        resolve(true);
      }
       resolve(true);
      console.log("JSON file has been saved.");
    });    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a waterfall call?

Comment: If you don't want it to be asynchronous  why not just use `fs.writeFileSync`?

Comment: You're iterating over `Array` instead of `aArray`

Comment: @BaliBalo I apologize, I put this to give my example, I already corrected it

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek perhaps in this case it is the most obvious. but I really want a solution that makes me learn. something like if this way did not exist.

Comment: @Cleriston I dont know what is that.. but you understad my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use writeFileSync.

```
aData={ ..... }
var aArray=["first.json","second.json","third.json"];
for(var i in aArray) {
  fs.writeFileSync(aArray[i], JSON.stringify(aData, null, 4), 'utf8')
}
```

Documentation : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

EDIT : 
Solution if you want to learn something new

```
aData={ ..... }
var aArray=["first.json","second.json","third.json"];
var recurringFunc = function() {
  if (aArray.length) {
    var fileName = aArray.shift();
    fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(aData, null, 4), 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('An error occured while writing JSON Object to File - ' + fileName);
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(fileName + 'file has been saved.');
      }
      recurringFunc();
    }
  }
}

recurringFunc();
```

Comment: No callback to `writeFileSync`

Comment: @BaliBalo Sorry my bad

Comment: @BaliBalo thanks!  perhaps in this case it is the most obvious. but I really want a solution that makes me learn. something like if this way did not exist.